# Drupal Commerce - Out of Stock, customer clicks to notify store owner to order more

Tags: commerce

When a product is out of stock, the store owner wants customers to have the ability to pre-order, without paying.
Similar to stock notify, but the store owner will manually email back customers once the stock arrives.
Something like'This product is out of stock, notify us, and we will order it in for you within 1 week.'

So it needs to collect: customer email and product SKU.
As many customers will be non-registered users, what would be the best way of capturing this data, and emailing it to the store owner?

I was thinking flags/rules module, or do you think a custom module would be simpler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a custom module doing the same for me. It collects the same info which you require & send the alert mail on cron job when stock resume. I had a github repo for it, which can help you doing it by custom module - https://github.com/drupler/commerce-stock-notify

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock_notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two similar kind of sandbox module for this particular functionality.

One was started by me - [Commerce Stock Notify](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Rajeevkr/2047369)

Another by itamar - [Commerce Stocklist](https://drupal.org/sandbox/itamar/1772176).

Both can be starting point for further development. As I left doing anything else for this as he started it before me, but my module do what you want except mail template which I was supposed to do later.

But now I think, I will spend some time on it & try to release stable soon :)